# Enable Azure SQL DAC (Dedicated Admin Connection)

Tags: sql-server, azure

This page claims that you can connect to Azure SQL with a Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC but not Data-tier Application):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver16
The article even goes so far as to specify that you need to connect directly to the database if you're on Azure SQL.

From SSMS `File->New->Database Engine Query`, with the "admin:" prefix on the servername, and the specific database, I get "Server was not found or not accessible".

From `sqlcmd -A -S <servername> -d <dbname>` I get "error occurred while obtaining the dedicated administrator connection (DAC) port"

In both cases adding port 1434 to the servername doesn't change anything.

Since I don't have sp_configure on Azure SQL, and don't see any configuration options in the Azure Portal, does anyone know how I can check to see if the DAC is enabled?

There's a surprising lack of google responses out there on this topic.  Has anyone been able to successfully connect to an Azure SQL DAC?

Comment: That URL takes you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ ?

Comment: Looking at [Diagnostic connection for database administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver16) it states *"When connecting to the Azure SQL Database with the DAC, you must also specify the database name in the connection string by using the `-d` option."* Your question suggests you didn't do that. It also gives an example after that statement: `sqlcmd -S serverName.database.windows.net,1434 -U sa -P <StrongPassword> -d AdventureWorks`

Comment: @ThomA Probably best migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: Unfortunately that requires voting, @Charlieface .

Comment: Thank you Larnu.  Have fixed the link and the sqlcmd that I tried to include the specific database as I did actually do that.